# Computer freeze and only reboot while playing

Tags: windows, freeze, crash, reboot, overclocking

So, i have read a lot and tried every solutions possible, that's why i'm here asking you. This freeze is different.

Anyway, what's happen is:
Turn on the computer and use it for EVERYTHING (except playing) works fine. But when i start play, after 10-30 min the game freeze and stay so for some seconds, then PC reboot himself. After that, i open the same game again and play normally for hours. No more freezes.
That's happen just the FIRST time after a normal shutdown. (Just for be more clear: i wake up, turn on pc, use it for hours and all is ok, then start play, after 10-30 min it freeze, reboot, no more freeze untill next "day").
This problem born after i update Windows to 2004. Now i have the 20H2 and still same.

Extra info: when i had the 2004, the pc freeze also while surfing online or just idle in desktop and freeze also more than just one time. But after some drivers (and Windows) update it freeze just ONE time and just while playing.
The same day i have updated Win to 2004 i have installed also XTU for overclock my CPU, i download from internet a OC profile, loaded and the pc freeze. But i set back all values to default again.

What i tried:

- All drivers are updated. Also chipset and other minor drivers.
- nVidia driver updated and reinstalled after DDU cleanup.
- Windows updated + other Microsoft products.
- Hard drive standby: off. Hard drive power settings: max performance.
- Windows power saving: performance profile.
- Temperatures and fans speed are under control and are ok.

I did other too, but now i don't remember all considering i have that problem since months.

My specs:

- MSI z170A pro
- Intel i7 6700K (is K but not OC*)
- 16GB RAM DDR4 3200MHZ OC (OC from 2016 and never a problem)
- MSI RTX 2060 Ventus XS
- OS on SSD Samsung 850 evo Sata3 - AHCI: ON
- Games on HDD Toshiba DT01ACA200 Sata3 - AHCI: ON (10% fragmentation)

Now the question is... is Windows? Drivers? Some OC params that are still "bad"? (but i doubt is this cause the freeze happen just ONE time "per day" and after reboot i can play normally)

Thanks to all!

Comment: Did you check the CPU & GPU temperature?

Comment: @harrymc Yep, i have another monitor where i see all temperatures, volts, fan speed and so on...

Comment: I would guess that some of the changes you did when overclocking are still sticking around. Try perhaps to reset the BIOS to defaults. Are you using the [latest BIOS](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/z170-a-pro) (not so new from 2018)? Or you could re-install the BIOS even if it's already this version.

Comment: @harrymc updated bios too to the new version (a month ago. But is the last one). About reset it to default, i can do it but the "weird" is that this freeze happen just the first time i play, after a reboot all will works... probably reset the bios will just give me more work to set back all other options and not solve the problem. Its seems like that at the first start, something essential is not loaded, but will load after a reboot. (if i turn on the PC and the reboot manually, will not work. Works only if freeze one time)

Comment: You mean that the problem occurs after a cold boot but not after a warm reboot? This might even be hardware, weak connection or capacitor or similar.

Comment: @harrymc yes, exactly. So, there is a way to solve or at least understand what and where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem occurs only after a cold boot but not after a warm reboot,
this perhaps points to a hardware problem, such as a weak connection or capacitor.

You may open up the computer and visually inspect the visible capacitors.
You may also reseat the RAM, do some cleaning, and in general press on all
contacts to ensure good connection.

If none of it helps, and you can't live with the problem (at least until it
becomes more evident than it's now), then a repair-shop might find the problem.
Note that such problems are very elusive, so even the repair-shop might have
trouble locating it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It took me hours to check every mm on the motherboard and all others hardware. But all seems fine, even not dust. The computer is clean and seems pretty new (i'm a maniac on this). Anyway, happen also if i play after an half day of normal work. So i think is not about warm and cold. And anyway, as i said, before that was freezing also in idle, now no more. Just one time and just if i play (whatever the game is). So the problem is "half solved", but not complete yet. Not sure 100% but i think is a software side fault.

Comment: Is the computer still under warranty?

Comment: no, 4 years old. I'm just looking for a small light in the dark that let me understand why that happen. For example, today i have turn on my pc at 8am, now is 18:00. In this 10 hours i was working with Visual Studio, debugging, video editing, rendering some 3D stuffs, music in background and watching video on YT and local files... all fine. Now i will start a game to see what's happen...

Comment: started play at 18:00, freezed and rebooted 18:08. After reboot, i have start play again, now is 20:10 and still no freeze... this exclude hardware problem, considering my pc is working since 12 hours no stop (excep this freeze of 18:08)  :(

Comment: This reminds me of my own freezes, which were due to the NVIDIA driver. In my case I totally fixed the problem by going back to driver version 451.67 and disabling auto-update. I don't know if this is an option for the RTX 2060.

Comment: well, since the first freeze i have updated nvidia driver 3 times to a new version. Can't be that is a bug of 4 different versions. Probably is some service or driver or something that DOSEN'T start in cold boot or manually reboot, but just in "freeze reboot". (or maybe is the opposite, a service, a driver or something that cause this freeze and start in boot BUT dosen't start anymore in freeze reboot)... I'm lost

Comment: Same as me, hoping over a period of a year that each NVIDIA update will fix the problem, until I decided to go back. I tried several versions in reverse and 451.67 seems like the last version before this "feature" was added. I signaled the problem twice to NVIDIA and never had any feedback. Try version [451.67](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/results/162105/) as a test and disable auto-update.

Comment: I have installed your driver (after a clean up) but nothing... still one freeze at day. I have also resetted the bios. Nothing, still one freeze, then works good. Ah and i have made tests too, with AIDA. CPU, FPU, RAM, HDD, SSD... all is ok. :(

Comment: Just for info, i got the problem. When i do a cold boot, the video card PICe link is "3.0 x16" after a freeze and a warm reboot, is going to be "3.0 x8". Unfortunately my motherboard let me change just the generation speed and not the lenght.

Comment: Did you check your [BIOS version](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/z170-a-pro#down-bios) and perhaps the Intel Chipset Driver, although they are already not very recent.

Comment: Yes, i have updated all driver one by one using the Hardware ID as reference and BIOS is up to date. Even not the RTX 3090 need a PICe 3.0 x16, is enough 3.0 x8 and i want use that, but my mobo keep boot with x16. But what i dont understand is: why freeze? i mean, i would understand a freeze if was x4 instead of x8, but x16 should be not a problem...